Setting editable's UseState false doesn't disable the react-native-floating-label-input fully in React Native
I am creating a user profile's section in my personal project. I am using the react-native-floating-label-input library for the input tag. By default all the input fields have editable false property. I am using a useState to toggle between email's editable to true or false. The code is reaching the function, the states are being toggled but the input tag  still accepts characters. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Here is my function for toggling in Profile.js
const [emailId, editEmailId] = useState(false)
   const [emailIsFocused, editEmailIsFocused] = useState(false)
   function editEmailAddress() {
       console.log("button pressed");
       editEmailId(!emailId);

   }

here is my input tag
 <View style={styles.labelWrapper}>
<StaticFloatingLabelInputComponent alignUnfocusedLabelLeft={true} customLabelStyles={styles.customLabelStyles} editable={emailId} label="Email Id"></StaticFloatingLabelInputComponent><TouchableOpacity style={styles.EditEmailLabel} onPress{editEmailAddress}>
<Image source={editLabel} style={{ height: 30, width: 30 }}></Image>
</TouchableOpacity>
</View> 

Relevant parts of code in staticFloatingLabelComponent component js
unction StaticFloatingLabelInputComponent(props) {

    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
    const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);
    
   useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("editable value: ", props.editable);
   },[props.editable]);

    return (
        <View style={{ marginTop: props.marginTop ? verticalScale(props.marginTop) : 0 }}>
            <FloatingLabelInput label={props.label}
                                value={inputValue}
                                staticLabel={true}
                                onFocus={() => {
                                    setIsFocused(true);
                                }}
                                onBlur={()=>{
                                    setIsFocused(false);
                                }}
                                isFocused={props.isFocused?props.isFocused:isFocused}
                                editable={props.editable} 
                                onChangeText={value => setInputValue(value)}
                                containerStyles={[styles.InputContainerStyles, { paddingHorizontal: props.alignUnfocusedLabelLeft ? 0 : horizontalScale(0), borderColor: isFocused ? colors.focusedInputFieldBorder : colors.unfocusedInputFieldBorder, backgroundColor: isFocused ? colors.focusedInputFieldBackground : colors.unfocusedInputFieldBackground, position: 'relative'}]}
                                customLabelStyles={styles.customLabelStyles}
                                labelStyles={styles.labelStyles}
                                inputStyles={styles.inputStyles}
            />
        </View>
    );
}


Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Can you please provide a minimum runnable code, to show what is happening, and what you expect to happen. It's impossible for us to see what's happening



return (
    <View style={{position: 'relative', marginTop: verticalScale(props.marginTop)}}>
        <FloatingLabelInput
            label={props.label}
            value={props.dateString}
            editable={props.editable}  // Use props.editable here instead of hardcoded false
            containerStyles={[ styles.InputContainerStyles, {
                borderColor: props.dateString ? colors.focusedInputFieldBorder : colors.unfocusedInputFieldBorder,
                backgroundColor: props.dateString ? colors.focusedInputFieldBackground : colors.unfocusedInputFieldBackground
            }
            ]}
            customLabelStyles={styles.customLabelStyles}
            labelStyles={styles.labelStyles}
            inputStyles={styles.inputStyles}
        />

        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0} style={styles.invisibleDatePickerButton} onPress={props.showDatepicker} >
            <Text></Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
);



Also, ensure that the emailId is correctly logged


const [emailId, setEmailId] = useState(false);  // you should initialize the state

function editEmailAddress() {
    console.log("button pressed");
    setEmailId(!emailId);  // Correct function to toggle the state
}





<StaticFloatingLabelInputComponent
    alignUnfocusedLabelLeft={true}
    customLabelStyles={styles.customLabelStyles}
    editable={emailId}
    label="Email Id"
/>
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.EditEmailLabel} onPress={editEmailAddress}>
    <Image source={editLabel} style={{ height: 30, width: 30 }}></Image>
</TouchableOpacity>
</View>



Let me know if this works!
